# How to calculate Page load time in Angular 2+ (SPA)?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, page-load-time

I am working on angular 6 and for google analytics, I need page load time on every route change. It would be helpful if someone tells me how to achieve it. I have tried lifecycle hooks of angular but they didn't work as expected.

Comment: What was the problem with lifecycle hooks?

Comment: I have used ngAfterViewinit and it was called multiple times. How would I know that page has rendered completely?